# Create private key and certificate using RSASSA PSS with openssl

Tags: openssl

how, if its possible to create a self signed key and certifactes using openssl with RSASSA-PSS (RFC 4065)?

I managed to use a existing (non-RSASSA-PSS) certificate with this padding mode:

*Signing*

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privateKey.pem -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -out pss.sha256 test.txt
```

*Verifying*

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -signature pss.sha256 test.txt
```

But I think these mode and saltlen should be (RFC 4065 must be) in the certificate?

If its not possible with openssl, what can I use instead?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Nice answer - why did you answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl/27931596#27931596 ? It dosnt matter.

Comment: You meant RFC 4056 and/or 4055 (not 4065), and the PSS parameters _may_ be in the certificate SubjPubKeyInfo if and only if the OID is id-RSASSA-PSS, but neither of these is required; _if_ that OID is used _and_ parameters are present, then (and only then) the signature(s) created under that key must match the stated parameters.

Answer (score 2):

`openssl genpkey`, `req` and `ca` (and maybe other openssl commands) allow to set some metadata so as to restrict the use of or certificate to specific constraints depending on the algorithm : eg. for RSA-PSS, min length for salt, digest method for signature...

- for `openssl genpkey`, the options are set with `-pkeyopt`, and they are transmitted to the CSR
- for `openssl req` and `ca`, the options are set with `-sigopt`

For example

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa-pss          \
    -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048           \
    -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_md:sha256       \
    -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_mgf1_md:sha256  \
    -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_saltlen:32      \
    -out privateKey.pem
```

Comment: What version of openssl is required? Mine is LibreSSL 2.8.3 and reports `Algorithm rsa-pss not found`

Comment: @chrisinmtown OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

Comment: That generates the private key with restrictions. Can a public key with similar restrictions be created using openssl? When I try piping that into `| openssl rsa -pubout | openssl asn1parse` I find that all the restrictions are lifted.

Comment: @ChristopherKing
The `openssl rsa` comman will produce a pkcs1 wrapped public key which does not contain the RSASSA-PSS metadata. Try this instead `openssl pkey -in /tmp/privateKey.pem -pubout -out /tmp/pubkey.pem`.