# How to generate private key using sha512-rsa-MGF1 and open ssl

Tags: openssl

Could you please help with the command to generate the private key using `sha512-rsa-MGF1` security algorithm?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  RSA private keys are RSA private keys - they have no SHA-512 or MGF1 component.  SHA-512 is a hashing algorithm that can be *used* in [OAEP-padded RSA encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding), and MGF1 is the usual mask generation function used in OAEP-padded RSA encryption.

Comment: @AndrewHenle+ MGF1 is also used in RSASSA-PSS signature, and OpenSSL can generate a keypair (and cert) restricted to PSS and certain (MGF1) parameters; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42898747/create-private-key-and-certificate-using-rsassa-pss-with-openssl and for background https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70413/why-does-openssl-differentiate-between-pss-and-non-pss